# Reading integers from file and store them in array C++

Tags: c++

this my code but i get infinite loop with the first number
I want to read the integers fromt he file and store them in the array

the file contains:

> 8 5 12 1 2 7

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int n = 0; //n is the number of the integers in the file ==> 12
    int num;
    int arr[100];

    ifstream File;
    File.open("integers.txt");
    while(!File.eof())
    {
        File >> arr[n];
        n++;
    }

    File.close();

    for(int i=0;i<12;n++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Any help please

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<12;n++)` ?

Comment: It appears that there are only 6 `int`s in that file.

Comment: Also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1870232

Comment: Typo in the for loop: 'i' instead of 'n'

Comment: Change the input `while` loop to `while (File >> arr[n])`.  This is the correct way to read from a file until EOF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @ravi but I some notes for you:

If you don't know how many integers are in the file and the file contains *only* integers, you can do this:

```
std::vector<int>numbers;
int number;
while(InFile >> number)
    numbers.push_back(number);
```

You need to `#include<vector>` for this.

---

it would be better if you read how many integers are in the file and then use loop to read them:

```
int count;
InFile >> count;
int numbers[count];       //allowed since C++11

for(int a = 0; a < count; a++)
    InFile >> numbers[a];
```

---

Note: *I didn't check for successful read, but it is a good practice to do so.*

Answer (score 3):

Your loop should be:-

```
for(int i=0; i < n ; i++)
{
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Or `while(n-->0){...}` ;)

Comment: @Quest then you'll get questions about the meaning of operator "-->" :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator